# Flutter Syncfusion chart add to list when button pressed

Tags: flutter, charts, syncfusion

So, I want to make a chart with a Syncfusion Cartesian chart, where the last 15 result of a calculation are shown on a date time x-axis. The results should be added to the list when a button is pressed on the page where it is calculated.

Answer (score -1):

We have analyzed your scenario and we have created a simple sample and attached below in which we have generated 15 random data for the chart and added it to the list on button click and rendered the cartesian chart. You check the sample to view how to add chart data to the list on button click.
Note: As we don’t know the exact calculation of the results of yours, we have kept the random generation of the data for the chart as the calculation part in the below-attached sample.

Sample link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oc9YjFz8i83TKGxqS6_AfO4_F2dPoMq3/view?usp=sharing